# Are boarding deadlines indicated on an airline's website legally binding?

Tags: air-travel

E.g. Air France lists boarding deadlines on its website:

> 15 minutes before the departure time, between Paris-Orly and metropolitan France destinations.
>
> 20 minutes before the departure time, for all other flights.

If the actual boarding deadline for the flight is before that deadline given on its website, is the passenger entitled to compensation?

Answer (score 1):

Under the common law in the United States, this would be an issue of contract law. When you buy a ticket, you are agreeing to provide $X, and Air France is agreeing to convey you as long as you comply with certain conditions. If you comply and they don't convey, they are in breach of the contract and suit would be appropriate if they do not refund you your ticket price. They would likely not be liable for any costs you incur from missing the plane, but they might be liable for the full price of a replacement ticket with a different airline, even if it cost more than the original ticket.